# Designing a data warehouse: action or status based

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

I am designing a data warehouse for a sales platform. There exists a group of users that offers and a group of users that demand entities.
The production data base holds two sources of information:

1. The current status of each entity and to which users it is assigned (this can be versatile, "placed a price for an order", "bought", "offered"). This can thus involve multiple users depending on the status.
2. An action log

Accordingly, there are two types of questions that the data warehouse can be asked. E.g.:

1. How many offers have been without an order yesterday at 9 am? (Status)
2. How many entities have been sold yesterday? (Action)

I aim for a simple star-schema where dimensions could be time, place, users, etc. But the question is: What would be the fact?

## First approach

My first idea was to introduce a fact table for every status. Then every fact would need a starting and end validity and as soon as the action log says, that a status changed, I need to get back to the fact table where the current status of the entity is stored and add the end-validity time stamp and afterwards add the new fact in the table of the new status of the entity (with a missing end-validity time stamp).

With this approach, it is quite simple to answer question 1 (Status) but impossible to answer question 2 (Action). Also, It seems non-trivial to update the data warehouse on each action.

## Second approach

An alternative idea was to simply store the action log in a star-schematized way. Every type of action becomes a fact. (Of course, the question 2 (Action) is most simple to answer but what about question 1 (Status)?

My Idea was to create date-parameterized views for each status:
For Example, to get all offers without an order yesterday at 9 am, I would have to get all actions that say "offered something" from before yesterday at 9am and I would have to subtract all offers that

1. an order has been placed on
2. that have been canceled until yesterday 9 am

I assume that the time-efficiency with this solution could be nonoptimal for reading. Although I thought, that data warehouses aim for trading write-efficiency for read-efficiency.

*So my question again*: How to design the fact-table to be able to answer both above questions with the minimum of complexity?

Comment: What time granularity do you need, and how many entities are you dealing with?

Answer (score 2):

What is being described by the OP is a "sales funnel" scenario, and you want to track movement of (something you have not clearly explained) through this funnel. That "something" might be "a real estate sale" or "hiring a job candidate", for example. The point is, the "something" is a **process**, and this process is what you are describing in your question.

You don't talk about what the "entity" is in your scenario - and it's not clear if the entity is the:

- "prospect/customer" (the buyer(s) or job candidate(s)) - the people/companies being targeted by the sales team
- "product/service" (the real estate or the job role(s)) - what the "sales team" is selling to the "prospect"
- "sales team" (the realtor(s) or the interviewer(s)) - company's people who would be working on moving the "prospect" through the "funnel"

Regardless, each of these are dimensions to the sales funnel process.

You are thinking of it wrong in terms of "status". What you really are tracking is movement of a "prospect" through stages/steps a "sales funnel". The sales funnel is a process of steps (your "statuses") and a "prospect"  moves through 1 or more of those steps.

You CAN model each step in the funnel as it's own FACT and you can have a FUNNEL_TRANSACTIONS_FCT potentially to link them, but that doesn't meet your requirement of a dynamic set of steps (statuses, as you call them).

A prospect moves to a different funnel step when some "action" (transaction) occurs e.g. quote requested, quote provided, quote accepted, order placed, contract is signed, order is canceled, etc. So, let each "status" (as you call it) be a transaction type (which would be a dimension in and of itself - to which new "statuses" can be added, and changes can be made, etc).

It is clear from here that your FACT table rows represent these "actions/transactions", the result of which lands the prospect in some step of the funnel at some certain time.

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner solution would obviously be to track states for every single attribute individually, as with your first approach.

It's not as bad as you make it though, as reconstructing a past state is as simple as just ignoring all new state changes introduced later on, so just a simple `WHERE date < ... GROUP BY attribute.order_id ORDER BY date DESC`, and then run an outer query on that reconstructed past snapshot.

Where I don't agree with you is using and "end" date. Use a follow-up reference instead, so you can easily filter for specific state transitions, that gives you the action log via a straight `JOIN`, as well as the current state by checking for `NULL`.

You should evaluate whether you actually want a star model, or just a monolithic `state` schema, expressing the whole state of an entity at any given time. That's a linear trade-off between storage space and query time.

You should probably record both the state, AND the action which caused the state change in a single record. Just in case there are actions which can not be expressed as a specific state chance, such as filtering by specific users and alike.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that the time-efficiency with this solution could be non optimal for reading. Although I thought, that data warehouses aim for trading write-efficiency for read-efficiency.

Easy question first, data warehouse should be designed for to be read efficient because it involves a lot of aggregations. OLTP on the other hand should be able to handle lots of transactions which means insert operations.

For the main question, your first approach would be the right one. I think the facts that you want to store here would be Sales, not the entity itself or any action upon the entity. An action should set the status on the entity (whatever entity that is).

The Sales table, may or may not be split in to two, i.e. you can have one table with entities and every status that's been set on them, or you can split it into Sales and SalesStatusHistory which hold FK to Sales, the status and the timestamp for the status.

Side note, if you use Sales and SalesStatusHistory tables doesn't mean the that the two are in star schema because they both are facts and you have to use them both together to get the fact, or put in another way, either one won't be fit as a dimension.

Once you've transformed entity and action to become Sales with status history, querying would just mean (most of the time) finding all the sales with the **latest** status within a time range and filtering by some statuses.

Example:

My transaction database creates an item when someone orders one. The item will have status based on the sales lifecycle (created, pending, purchased, paid and cancelled). The sales table would be something like this:

```
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| item   | status    | timestamp           |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| Item 1 | Created   | 2016-12-19 03:32:04 |
| Item 1 | Purchased | 2016-12-19 03:40:04 |
| Item 1 | Cancelled | 2016-12-19 04:40:04 |
+--------+-----------+---------------------+
```

The latest status of Item 1 is Cancelled; all purchases until 4 am will include Item 1.